# Flexy layout resizing lag

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've created a flexy layout to hold an image in two columns so that the image is never distorted and always fill the area vertically without javascript forcing reflows:

```css
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.red {
  background: #faa;
}
.blue {
  background: #aaf;
}
.green {
  background: #afa;
}
.large_container {
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80%;
}

.image {
    height: 100%;
}

.img-container {
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    height: 100%;
}

.text_container {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
    height: 1000vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="red large_container">
  <div class="blue small_margin img-container">

    
    <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x850"/>
  </div>
  <div class="green text_container">
        <h1>This div Resizes</h1>
    <p>Best viewed fullscreen, there are also iframe-related loading bugs on the relayout</p>
    <p>This is not good :(</p>  
  </div>
</div>
```

The layout works exactly as intended, statically. When the page resizes, chrome layout engine "lags" and generally does all kind of weird things:

[image]

It's especially visible on downsizing from fullscreen, the image resizing happens slightly after flexbox calculations and the blue background appears.

Any way to trigger a flexy relayout from javascript, until chrome bugs get fixed?

Comment: Remove red, blue class from the parent div.